# Multi-Label Classifier in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, multilabel-classification

I want to develop a multi-label classifier with TensorFlow, i try to mean there exists multiple label which contains multiple classes. To illustrate you can image the situation like:

- label-1 classes: lighting raining, raining, partial raining, no raining
- label-2 classes: sunny, partly cloudy, cloudy, very cloudy.

I want to classify these two labels with neural network. For now, i used different class label for every (label-1, label-2) pair classes. Which means i have 4 x 4 = 16 different label.

By training my model with

## current loss

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(ys * tf.log(prediction), reduction_indices=[1])) 

# prediction is sofmaxed
loss = cross_entropy + regul * schema['regul_ratio'] # regul things is for regularization 
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
```

However i think that a multi-label training will work nicer in such a condition.

- My features will be [n_samples, n_features]
- My labels will be [n_samples, n_classes, 2]

n_samples of [x1, x2, x3, x4 ...]  # features

n_samples of [[0, 0, 0, 1],  [0, 0, 1, 0]] # no raining and cloudy

How can i make a softmax probability distribution predictor with tensorflow. Is there any working example for multilabel problem like this one. How will be my loss tensor like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just have your network produce two different outputs?

network -> prediction1 and prediction2

where prediction1 and prediction2 are both [#,#,#,#] but what I describe below works even if they're different sizes.

Then just run

```
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction1, labels_1))
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction2, labels_2))

loss = loss1 + loss2
```